# How to speed up file uploading using Nginx + uWSGI

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I have used nginx built-in functionality **clientbodyinfileonly** to upload my files. And in order to know its performance. I used Apache ab to test it.

when I set **concurrency level** to **100**,

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 -p xxxx.rar -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://??????
```

the result was

```
Requests per second:    1477.95 [#/sec] (mean)
```

When the **concurrency level** is set to 120, I got 502 errors.

```
connect() to unix:/???/uwsgi.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

The nginx config as following shown [ visit [Nginx direct file upload without passing them through backend](https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw/nginx-direct-file-upload-without-passing-them-through-backend) for more details ]

```
location /upload {
        auth_request               /upload/authenticate;

        client_body_temp_path      /tmp/;
        client_body_in_file_only   on;
        client_body_buffer_size    16M;
        client_max_body_size       80M;

        uwsgi_pass_request_headers on;

        uwsgi_param                X-FILE $request_body_file;
        uwsgi_pass_request_body    off;
        uwsgi_pass                 unix://tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        include  uwsgi_params;
}

location = /upload/authenticate {
        uwsgi_pass              unix://tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        uwsgi_pass_request_body off;
        uwsgi_param             CONTENT-LENGTH "";
        uwsgi_param             X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        include  uwsgi_params;
}
```

The way I took to around it was providing much more back-end servers together with **upstream** directive. And now the 502 went away. However, the TPS is still less than 1600 no matter how many uWSGi instances I added [ in practice, I used at most 8 instance, each with 2 processes ].

I also looked at the cpu, memory usage [ top, free, vmstat] during loading test. They are not too high.

Why the performance does not become better even if I used more uWSGI instances?? How could I know where to optimize?

The machine used is AWS EC2 with 2 CPUs ( 2.5GHz), 4G memory. And the file size used to upload is 30K.

Comment: what you mean with 8 instances with 2 process each ? from your config it looks like you are using a single unix socket. Maybe you mean a single instance with 8 process and 2 threads each ? Btw for an EC2 instance they looks pretty good number, you have to take in account there are dozens of player in the game (included ab not being the best tool for this kind of tests)

Comment: @roberto, the config above is the initial version. Later, I used 8 uWSGI instance, each start 2 process. The latest version is using `upstream internal_unix { server unix://uwsgi1.sock; server unix://uwsgi2.sock; server unix://uwsgi2.sock; server unix://uwsgi3.sock; ... } ` and the value of **uwsgi_pass** changed to **internal_unix**.

Comment: @roberto: another thing is, you have said that **ab** is not a good tool here. So, what is the better tool? could you share me? thanks!

Comment: httperf is generally a good tool for the job